# Aristotelian terminology, dynamis and entelechy

Tags: aristotle

Does Aristotle ever use a collective term (such as `mode') for ἐντελέχεια and δύναμις?

Answer (score 3):

You can see :

- Aristotle, [Metaphysics : Book Theta](https://books.google.it/books?id=BikKAQAAMAAJ) (Stephen Makin editor)

and the [review](http://bmcr.brynmawr.edu/2007/2007-07-60.html) by Daniel P.Maher.

It seems that we have a (not rare in A) case of "multiplicity" of meaning :

> The general schema relates *energeia* and *dunamis*, which is "potentiality" here, but "capacity" at the lower level. Thus, in the commentary, "capacity" and "potentiality" mark whether Makin has in mind *dunamis* in the use coordinated with change or *dunamis* in the schematic use coordinated with actuality. In this light, the introduction seems to have understated the distinction between the two translations of *dunamis* [*footnote #6* : On page xxxv, Makin says the term *dunamis* is "already overworked, referring both to a capacity and to a potentiality," which seems to imply two distinct meanings.] In the commentary Makin works out interesting distinctions among many kinds of capacity: active and passive, rational and non-rational, innate capacities and those acquired by learning and by teaching. These many senses of "capacity" are ordered in a "focal analysis" around the primary type, the "active capacity" [...]. Whether "potentiality" at the schematic level is only an extension of the very same notion encountered at the level of capacity-change may be disputed, but it is helpful to recognize the distinct usage of "capacity" and "potentiality."

Comment: Also related : http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/10011/5154

Answer (score 1):

According to Heidegger, the relevant collective term appears to be *eidos*, form or essence.  However, since *energeia* is regarded as prior to *dynameis* the former would be more relevant to the question of 'mode'.

> In Greek thought *energeia* means “standing in the work,” where “work”
>   means that which stands fully in its “end.”  But in turn the
>   “fully-ended or fulfilled” [das “Vollendete”] does not mean “the
>   concluded,” any more than *telos* means “conclusion.”  Rather, in
>   Greek thought *telos* and *ergon* are defined by
>   [*eidos*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eidos); they name the manner
>   and mode in which something stands “finally and finitely” [“endlich”]
>   in its appearance. ...
>
> Aristotle says this in his own way in a sentence we take from the
>   treatise that deals explicitly with *entelecheia* (Meta. , 8, 1049 b
>   5): *fanerin oti proteron energeia dynameis estis*: “Manifestly
>   standing-in-the-work is prior to appropriateness for....”

continues at : https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/10011/5154

Also in the linked PDF:

[M. Heidegger: On The Essence and Concept of *Physis* in Aristotle's Physics](https://religiousstudies.stanford.edu/people/thomas-sheehan/publications#translations), page 24

> Aristotle characterizes *uhl* as *to dunamei*.  *Dynameis* means the
>   capacity, or better, the appropriateness for.... The wood present in
>   the workshop [281] is in a state of appropriateness for a “table.”

So *dunameis* as 'capacity' appears to have much less to do with 'mode' than *energeia*.