# The concept of nature in the Greek philosophy

Tags: aristotle, plato, socrates, ancient-philosophy, greeks

My question is: Is it possible to point to a development in the concept of "nature" in the period between pre-Socratic philosophers and Aristotle (inclusive)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe useful: Gerard Naddaf, [The Greek Concept of Nature (2005)](https://books.google.it/books?id=9bgxzMhxiDsC&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Comment: You may have a look at Peter's " Greek philosophical terms".

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good account here, also included in Pathmarks.

From the translator, Thomas Sheehan.  See the 1998 section:

[M. Heidegger: On The Essence and Concept of *Physis* in Aristotle's Physics](https://religiousstudies.stanford.edu/people/thomas-sheehan/publications#translations)

> The Romans translated φύσις by the word *natura*. *Natura* comes from
>   *nasci*, “to be born, to originate,” as in the Greek root γεν- . *Natura* means “that which lets something originate from itself.” . . .
>
> The first coherent and thoughtful discussion (“first” because of its
>   way of questioning) of the essence of φύσις comes down to us from the
>   time when Greek philosophy reached its fulfillment.  It stems from
>   Aristotle and is preserved in his ... (Lectures given - or better,
>   “Lectures heard” - on φύσις).

Comment: Heidegger is not a good source for studying ancient philosophers, he just uses them as a springboard for expounding his own ideas, see [Most, Heidegger's Greeks](https://www.bu.edu/arion/files/2010/03/Greeks-Most.pdf):"*Heidegger  himself  sometimes  took  care  to  distinguish his  own  philosophical  project  from  a  historical  reconstruction... What  is  interesting  about  Heidegger’s  Greeks  is  not  that they are Greeks, but that they are Germans and that they are Heidegger’s.*"

Comment: I suppose Heidegger admits that in the above essay where he writes one of his main points: "Thus the assertion, “Clearly actuality is prior to potentiality” seems to be evidently in error, for the contrary is more plausible. Surely in order for something to be “actual” and to be able to be “actual,” it must first be possible. Thus, potentiality is prior to actuality. **But if we reason this way, we are not thinking either with Aristotle or with the Greeks in general.**" (more context [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/10011/5154))